# Where to put server-side PHP? and how to link it to client-side?

Tags: php, html

Our university provides a public folder to every student where we put out html files and host our own website.

My question is:
Am I able to do some server-side programming in this situation? I found this example from w3school:

client-side:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

server-side:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I put both files under the folder, but nothing works. I am sorry that this might be a stupid question. But I would really like to find out what is happening.

Thank you guys so very much in advance!

Comment: We have no idea how to answer this without understanding your university's hosting environment. I might suggest contacting their IT department with this question.

Comment: Does your university server support PHP?

Comment: Put this into a file named `phpinfo.php` and post the results after you navigate to it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: for php, the server side code and the client side code goes into the same file

Comment: @Markasoftware - That's not necessarily the case.

Comment: don't -1 the question, this person is simply new to php. Instead of downvoting the question because he doesn't know much about php yet, we should try to explain it to him/her

Comment: @JaredFarrish not always, but it often (maybe even usually) is

Comment: @Markasoftware - That's a gross generalization that leads to confusion and bad coding practices. It's not, and shouldn't be said to be so.

Comment: well, often, you use it to, say, load the username into the document where it should be displayed, fill out multi-page forms, etc, and you have to understand how that works to use php

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for helping. I am new to PHP, so I don't know much. Thank you both for trying to help, please don't fight though ^_^. If the client side and server side are both in the same file, the action = "welcome.php" would not make sense, right? then what should I do then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The host space they provide may not have enabled PHP for you to use

Comment: Thank you, that is a possibility I think.